# How to resolve ImportError: No module named bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to run some python code, I've installed Python and BeautifulSoup, but I'm getting this error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

`main.py`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('index.html', 'r') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    print(content)
```

After running `python main.py` in terminal

```
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from bs4) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (2.5)
```

`terminal error`

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

Comment: Try to make sure you are using the correct Python version that has `BeautifulSoup` installed, may `python3` instead.

Comment: What does it say if you do `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: Could you perform a `which python` to see which python you are using and a `pip freeze` and see if beautiful soup is in your installed packages ?

Comment: What Python Version you are using ? Once try reinstalling this library.

Answer (score 0):

I often get `ImportError` on `BeautifulSoup` too, these are some of the reasons behind this problem:

- If you're on Windows, try running `pip install` from an administrator shell. If you're on Linux, try running it with `sudo`
- For Windows try running `Get-Command python`. For Linux, try `which python`. Go into the folder it indicates. If you're not using `venv`s, you will find the `lib` folder where `BeautifulSoup` should be installed.
- Try running `pip install beautifulsoup4` instead of `pip install bs4` or `pip install BeautifulSoup4`
- Try operating inside a `venv`! Create a new `venv` with `python -m venv venv`, enter it with `.\venv\Scripts\activate` (Windows) or `source venv/bin/activate` (Linux) and try reinstalling `beautifulsoup4`
- Make sure you are using the correct `pip` for `python 3.9`!

I can't really know which of these will work, probably none, but I hope it may help!